# object model to implement tranches, how?

Tags: python, object

I’m looking for any ideas on how to implement tranches in objected oriented programming, e.g. in Python.

I’ll give a simple example of what I’m trying to accomplish.

A plant produces pencils. Monthly production varies. The pencils are identical and they have a market price. Market price varies. Agents A, B and C belong to the senior tranche. Agent A is contractually bound to buy half of the production, up to total volume of 1000 pencils for the fixed price of EUR 4. Similarly, agents B and C are contractually bound to buy a quarter, each, of the production up to total volume of 500 pencils, each, for a fixed priced of EUR 5. In addition, Agent A has an option to buy an additional 1000 pencils for a strike price of EUR 5, at her discretion. Agent D belongs to the junior tranche. Agent D has the option to buy 5000 pencils from whatever is left from the senior tranche for a strike price of EUR 3, at her discretion.

My question is, given two vectors, each 24 elements, of production volumes and market prices, how many pencils does Agent D end up buying?

As I see it, the problem is how to link various objects of type Agent and how to get the pencils to flow through this “net” of Agents, so that each Agent grabs whatever that Agent is obliged to/has the right to and passes the unwanted ones to the next Agent/group of Agents. The challenge is that there can be multiple Agents at each tranche.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a bit ambiguous, but I'll try! As I see it, you start with some number `n` of pencils at market price `p`.

1. You sell `a:=min(n//2,1000)` of them to agent A at EUR 4.
2. You sell `b:=min(n//4,1000)` of them to agent B at EUR 5.
3. You sell `c:=min(n//4,1000)` of them to agent C at EUR 5.
4. You ask agent A if she wants any of the remaining pencils; she buys `a' <= min(n-a-b-c,1000)` of them at EUR 5.
5. You ask agent D if she wants any of the remaining pencils; she buys `d <= min(n-a-b-c-a',5000)` of them at EUR 3.

(I don't understand why you have 24-element vectors. Is that over two years or something? I've also made an ordering assumption -- if you ask agents A and D simultaneously whether they want some of the remaining pencils, they might both ask for them!)

---

The first three steps are entirely determined by your contract; the agents have no say in the matter. Those are easy for you to compute, so all you need to do is set up some way to ask agents how many pencils they want when they have a choice.

To do this, I would assume that you have `Agent` objects with a `query` method. You would call

```
agent.query(number_of_pencils_remaining, maximum_buyable, market_price)
```

and this should return an integer indicating how many pencils the agent wants to buy. This should be implemented separately -- I assume the agents will want to do some computation based on their forecasts and the market price before they buy.

Does that make sense?

---

In pseudocode:

```
class Agent(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def query(number_of_pencils_remaining, maximum_buyable, market_price):
        return 0

for price, volume in zip(...,...):
    sell(quantity=min(volume//2, 1000), to=A, price=4)
    sell(quantity=min(volume//4, 1000), to=B, price=5)
    sell(quantity=min(volume//4, 1000), to=C, price=5)

    sell(quantity=A.query(...), to=A, price=5)
    sell(quantity=D.query(...), to=D, price=3)
```

Comment: True, my question is somewhat ambiguous. I should have mentioned that I’m trying to come up with a more abstract object oriented structure that would do exactly this, in some neat way. Since the Agents are read from a database, the structure should facilitate and number of Agents, with different types of characteristics, placed at various tranche levels, i.e. Agents at level x, get whatever ever is left from the upper level x+1.

Comment: Conceptually, I’m thinking about a waterfall where the flow of water represents the pencils. Initially the water flows into some higher level basins and fills them. Next, the water flows into the lower level basins and fills them as well. And so on.